# Given f(x) =$ a/x^2 + x $

Tags: calculus

*Use the second-derivative test to show that if a is positive then the graph has a local minimum, and if a is negative then the graph has a local maximum.*

So part 1 of this asked to find the critical points. 
I calculated the first derivative to be $$\frac{2a}{x^3} + 1$$
Then the second derivative to be $$\frac{6a}{x^4} $$ with no roots.

Comment: first derivative should be $-\frac{2a}{x^3} +1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is incorrect.

The first derivative should be:

$$f'(x) = -\frac{2a}{x^3} + 1 = 0$$

Solving we get:

$$\frac{2a}{x^3} = 1,\ x^3 = 2a,\ x = (2a)^{1/3}$$

Then we have the second derivative to be:

$$f''(x) = \frac{6a}{x^4}$$

Now we check,

If $a > 0$, $f''(x) > 0$ and $f(x)$ has a local minimum.

If $a < 0$, $f''(x) < 0$ and $f(x)$ has a local maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you've got the second derivative: note $x^4 > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$. So the sign of the second derivative, which determines whether a stationary point is a local minimum or maximum, is determined by the sign of $a$.

Comment: (As pointed out by the comment and the other answer, your first derivative is incorrect; it just so happened your second derivative was correct...)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first and second derivatives respectively are:
 $$-\frac{2a}{x^3} + 1, \frac{6a}{x^4} $$

If $a$ is positive there is a local minimum at $ x_{extremum} = (2 a )^{1/3} $ OK, but:

when $a$ is negative there is *no maximum* , as there is *no (real) root at all* which you can refer to, second derivative sign makes no sense regarding extremality.

It will help to graph together $ f(x) = 1/x^2 + x $  and $ g(x) = - 1/x^2 + x. $